# trying to place two pyspark dataframes side by side

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join to dataframes side by side, they don't have any column in common

I have tried below code but doesn't seem to get proper output

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
df_assembled = df_assembled.withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id() )
outlier_df = outlier_df.withColumn( "id", monotonically_increasing_id() )
result_df = df_assembled.join(outlier_df,df_assembled.id == outlier_df.id, how='inner')
```

I tried to print the count() of the dataframe, but the combined dataframe has a different count :

```
print(df_assembled.count())
print(outlier_df.count())
print(result_df.count())
```

output :

```
170856
170856
6144
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `monotonically_increasing_id()` will generate increasing but random values, something like (25769803776, 51539607552, 77309411328, ...) and not (1, 2, 3, ...), so it's not guaranteed that you will have same values for both dataframes, what you want to do is to generate an id column with values starting from 1 and increased by 1 (1, 2, 3, 4 ...), you can use `row_number` for that (note: this will move both dataframes into a single partition, which is not good for performance)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
w = Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())
df_assembled = df_assembled.withColumn("id", row_number().over(w))
outlier_df = outlier_df.withColumn("id", row_number().over(w))
result_df = df_assembled.join(outlier_df, df_assembled.id == outlier_df.id, how='inner')
print(df_assembled.count())
print(outlier_df.count())
print(result_df.count())
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation , i was thinking to convert pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe so as to concatenate

Comment: You can do that but then you lose spark distributed power.

Comment: yeah, true though